# Is it possible to test a google cloud Firestore trigger function locally with function-framework?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with the cloud function in GCP project without using firebase. I can't find a solution to test a firestore trigger function locally with the function-framework package for node js, any recommendations for a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is an emulator for several services that allows you to trigger cloud functions locally:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

This way you can spin up a local firestore emulator with an UI

https://firebase.blog/posts/2020/05/local-firebase-emulator-ui

Comment: thank you for your response, but I mentioned that I'm not using firebase. I 'm using  firestore emulateur beta and I can't find an example of code or logic to work with .

Comment: I work with firestore too and was able to spin up a local version and trigger cloudfunctions with those links. It's called firebase emulator because firestore is part of firebase. Take a look at the links and you will see that it will show you how to use the firestore emulator